# Cocoa Touch: How to have a controller always visible over other views

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm relatively new to Cocoa programming, but I've managed to figure a fair amount out. One thing I haven't been able to figure out yet is how to have an element that is visible over all views. Like a volume control that is always visible just above the tab bar at the bottom of the screen.

How should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to bring a view to the front, you can use `bringSubviewToFront:`, like so:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourSubview];
```

If you need to position subviews so that they overlap in a certain way, you'll want to make use of [CALayer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html). Just be aware that overlapping UIControl elements goes against Apple's Human Interface guidelines.